# How MUST the directory for a plugin be structured?

Tags: plugins, directory

I get the basic plugin concept. 
I've read the Codex article on [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Creating_a_Plugin)

That article talks about the "main plugin file".

How does Wordpress determine "the main plugin file" ?

**Q1:**
Is it legal / supported to  have a plugin that is structured like this:

- pluginname/
- pluginname/mainfile.php
- pluginname/supportingcode-1.php
- pluginname/supportingcode-2.php
- pluginname/Readme.txt
- etc..

?

**Q2:**
If so, how does wordpress determine which php file is the main plugin file?

---

I have seen recommendations that say "I structure my code *this way*":

- pluginname/
- pluginname/mainfile.php
- pluginname/inc/supportingcode-1.php
- pluginname/inc/supportingcode-2.php
- pluginname/Readme.txt
- etc..

**Q3:**
Is the use of a subdirectory (like `inc/` in the above example) a requirement when the PHP code spans 
multiple modules?

**Q4:**
Is it true that there should be a maximum of ONE php file in the main plugin directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly your first question 'How does WordPress determine the main PHP file' is answered directly in the main 'Writing a plugin' guide on [file headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How does Wordpress determine "the main plugin file" ?

It is the file in your plugin that contains the plugin header comment

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: A fresh example
 * Plugin URI:  http://example.com
 * Description: Foo makes a bar
 * Version:     2012-06-14.1426
 * Author:      John Doe
 * Author URI:  http://example.com
 * TextDomain:  your_textdomain
 * License:     MIT
 * LicenseURI:  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
```

> Q1: Is it legal / supported to have a plugin that is structured like this:

Yes. *Every* directory structure (as far as supported by servers) is legal.

> Q2: If so, how does wordpress determine which php file is the main plugin file?

See above ↑

> Q3: Is the use of a subdirectory (like inc/ in the above example) a requirement when the PHP code spans multiple modules?

Requirement? No. Nicer to read: yes. Easier to maintain: Also yes.

> Q4: Is it true that there should be a maximum of ONE php file in the main plugin directory?

No. Simply no.

### Summed up

The way you're organizing your files and directories completely is up to you, your personal preferences and nothing else. If you want to make it easier for you to maintain and for other developers to step through your code, then you should use some sort of file/directory organization.

### Examples

I personally append `.class.php` as extension, when I got a class in it. I also name my files right exactly like the class. The reason is simple: My "main plugin file" - which is my *`bootstrap`* class, normally cares about loading all the needed stuff.

```
// inside my PREFIX_bootstrap class:
public static $includes = array(
    'settings'          => false // Parent class - no need to hook
   ,'settings_extended' => true  // Extending class - hooks static init() on `init` hook
);

public function construct()
{
    // The prefix for every class in my plugin
    $prefix = 'my_class_prefix_';

    foreach ( $this->files as $handle => $hook )
    {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."{$handle}.class.php";

        if ( ! $hook )
            continue;

        $class = $prefix.$handle;
        class_exists( $class ) AND add_action( 'init', array( $class, 'init' ), 1 );
    }
}
```

This means my classes and files are named like the following:

- `settings.class.php` AND `settings_extended.class.php`
- `my_class_prefix_settings` AND `my_class_prefix_settings_extended`

I also do some basic directory organization, like storing all `js/css/img` files in directories named like this.

Some people use (for larger plugin) folders that are named `inc/includes/assets/extensions/lib/etc.`. I'd recommend to use subfolders for large plugins only. If you got additional stuff like widgets, etc., then you could use specific subfolders for them.

**Last word:** No, nothing what you've found is *true*, those (like the stuff I showed you) are only recommendations.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  So the header comment is the way wordpress finds the "main plugin file".  It loads only that one, correct?  And of course any other subsidiary php files that are required or included by that one.  Correct?   I guess it just wasn't clear to me in the codex.   I just re-read it, and I see what it's saying now.  I wish it would say something like "Wordpress looks for the one file in your zip that has this special header; it ignores other files in the zip." or something along those lines. anyway thanks.

Comment: Yes, it loads only the files, that you specify plus the "main" file. Be aware, that there are hooks that have page specific parts, to prevent loading everything on every request.